# Browsing an SVN Repository

Tags: svn

I'm trying to browse an SVN repository without having to check it out:

- Is it possible to do this locally (on Unix)?
- Is this possible with ssh access?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [svnlook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09s03.html)

> a command-line utility for examining different aspects of a Subversion repository. It does not make any changes to the repository—it's just used for “peeking”. `svnlook` is typically used by the repository hooks, but a repository administrator might find it useful for diagnostic purposes.
>
> Since `svnlook` works via direct repository access (and thus can only be used on the machine that holds the repository), it refers to the repository with a path, not a URL.
>
> If no revision or transaction is specified, `svnlook` defaults to the youngest (most recent) revision of the repository...

Comment: svnlook tree seems to do the trick, with the -N argument for when you only want to see one level

Answer (score 83):

svn ls works.
e.g.

```
svn ls http://my.svnserver.com/trunk/foo
```

Try this on the command line:

```
svn ls http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk
```

Comment: I guess it depends on the meaning of "browse". If you simply want to look at the directories and file names, svn ls will suffice. Try the command I posted above.

Comment: I agree - svn ls works fine for me - there is no need to check out the workspace to do that. I am not sure though if any other functionality is required when you say "browse" a repository.

Comment: Can you do svn ls on a repository? I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Yes. Subversion can connect over several protocols file:// http:// https:// svn://. But you may have a version that does not have support for all protocols compiled in, or a required library cannot be found. For example, libneon is required for http/https and it requires openssl for https. So If you're missing those you'll have a problem with those protocols.

Did you try the exact command I posted above against the Apache repository? If that failed (it works for me) you should probably tell us the error message you're getting.

Comment: If you want to see file dates and sizes use the -v option e.g.: `svn ls -v http://my.svnserver.com/trunk/foo`

Comment: For local file systems it is something like `svn ls file:///$PWD/subdir/trunk`.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on what platform you're on you can also use:

- Windows - Tortoise SVN (https://tortoisesvn.net/): TortoiseSVN Repository Browser
- OS X - Versions (http://versionsapp.com/)
- Linux - Rabbit VCS (http://rabbitvcs.org/)

I find a terminal great for power use, but when you want to just see something or dig though directories, a visual version is a little bit more rewarding.

Comment: Useful. I will consider checking those out if I need to do more browsing in the future

Comment: Not sure Rabbit VCS will do any good in this case, since it seems to be exclusively a file manager plugin and only works with local copies

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the type of access you have, one of these options might be good:

svn look (as noted above) and svn info (also in the svn book: google for it) are two good command-line options.  They work on the local machine if you're logged in, but they also work remotely over the network.

If the svn repository is running with a public web server, you may be able to simply browse to it using your browser, e.g. your.svn.server.com/your/svn/path.

Many svn administrators also install ViewVC (http://www.viewvc.org/).  You can try browsing to your.svn.server.com/viewvc to see if you get anything.

Editing to let commenters change their mind ;)